# find_or_initialize_by and has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have an xml file the user imports data from. This creates a record in the `Player` model.
At the same time, I want a record to be created in the `Membership` association.

Both of the above should only be triggered if the record does not already exist.
This is a shortened version of the method:

```
@player = self.players.find_or_initialize_by_name_and_archetype(name, archetype)
if @player.save
  self.memberships.create(:player_id => @player.id)
end
```

Now `find_or_initialize_by` works, but a `Membership` is still created for each player, basically ignoring the if condition.

How can one go about doing this in a concise way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@player` gets set from a find, or an initialize, calling save on it can still return true, even if it's not a new record—try it out in console by finding an object, not changing anything, calling save on it, and you'll still get true so long as it's a valid object.

That being said, I think you want your condition to be more along the lines of

```
if @player.new_record? && @player.save
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried it out in console and indeed it did return true. For some reason I thought save would be false if it only found the record and did not initialize it.

Comment: `save` will only return false is the record is not valid (based on validations). Glad it worked out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the cleaner way would be to add uniqueness constraint to memberships on I don't know who `self` is in your code (a `Team`?) like that

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :memberships, :before_add => :validates_membership
```

I would just silently drop the database call and report success.

```
def validates_membership(membership)
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if self.memberships.include? membership
end
```

ActiveRecord::Rollback is internally captured but not reraised.
Then you can just call `self.memberships.create(:player_id => @player.id)` and there will be no duplicate memberships created.
If you wish you can add uniqueness constraint on the database level `add_index :memberships, [ :team_id, :player_id ], :unique => true, :name => 'by_team_and_player`.

And, the last but not least (some would say you should do that first), you can add tests to verify membership uniqueness.